# Can I return to the states after two days?

Tags: visas, usa

I am traveling to the states in November For three months.  I want to travel America for a year before I go back to my education.  I have my return flight booked, and I return back to Ireland for three days, then I've another flight to go back out and join my friends and family on continuing our traveling around the states?

Is this possible to do or?  Coming home for three days? Then back again?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your nationality and your visa, this is hard to answer. But assuming you are a national and carry a passport from any of the VWP countries listed here:- http://london.usembassy.gov/niv/vwp.html, and you are visiting on a VWP the first time, you will have no problem doing what you suggest.

If, however your second visit is on the VWP also, you will not be entitled to stay longer than 90 days in the US and you may have to answer some very awkward questions from immigration.  Be aware that if the immigration officer suspects you may not leave the US within the stipulated 90 days, he will refuse you entry.